# String in Cython functions

Tags: python, string, cython

I'd like to do this to pass a string to a Cython code:

```
# test.py
s = "Bonjour"
myfunc(s)

# test.pyx
def myfunc(char *mystr):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(len(mystr)):           # error! len(mystr) is not the length of string
        print mystr[i]                    # but the length of the *pointer*, ie useless!
```

but as shown in comment, here it doesn't work as expected.

---

**The only workaround I've found is passing also the length as parameter of `myfunc`. Is it correct? Is it *really* the simplest way to pass a string to a Cython code?**

```
# test.py
s = "Bonjour"
myfunc(s, len(s))


# test.pyx
def myfunc(char *mystr, int length):
    cdef int i
    for i in range(length):  
        print mystr[i]
```

Comment: From the [Cython tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html): "Generally speaking: unless you know what you are doing, avoid using C strings where possible and use Python string objects instead." I'd recommend just declaring it as a `str`.

Comment: Can you post the code that would work with `str` @user2357112 ? Would it really be `str` or `c_string` or something else?

Comment: Well, `char *mystr` in C is just a pointer to some array (of characters or numbers), there is no way to know how large it is unless you explicitly provide its size with  `int length` as you have done. If you want to avoid this, use `def myfunc( str  mystr):` as @ user2357112  has indicated.

Comment: Ok great! @user2357112 I'll accept your answer if you post it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simplest, [recommended](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html) way is to just take the argument as a Python string:

```
def myfunc(str mystr):
```